# How to retrieve text box value ajax in to another form

Tags: jquery, ajax

hi i am trying  to retrieve value of textbox using ajax on to another form without refresh but it is not working

Here is my code

```
<script>
        function sendsms() {
            var exam = new XMLHttpRequest();
            exam.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (exam.readyState == 4) {
                    document.getElementById("RightPaneContainerDiv").innerHTML = exam.responseText;
                }

            }
            exam.open("GET", "freetrailsend.php?message=" + document.getElementById("cwc").value,"service=" + document.getElementById("dropdown").value, true);
            exam.send(null)
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

where i am wrong in this code

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct this line

```
exam.open("GET", "freetrailsend.php?message=" + document.getElementById("cwc").value,"service=" + document.getElementById("dropdown").value, true);
```

with this

```
exam.open("GET", "freetrailsend.php?message=" + document.getElementById("cwc").value + "&service=" + document.getElementById("dropdown").value, true);
```

Comment: Don't forget to encode those URI components, so that special characters don't screw things up: http://stackoverflow.com/a/332888/759924

Comment: @anilkumar... i think above answer will solve your problem if need more help then comment...